# Sqllite SQLiteDataReader returns enpty reader while SQLiteDataAdapter returns the right result

Tags: sqlite

I have trouble with Sqllite SQLiteDataReader. Using the same connection string and the same sql statement SQLiteDataReader returns empty reader while SQLiteDataAdapter returns suspected record.

I this case I try to get the record with the highest value in the Id field.
The database contains several records with unique values in the Id field, but the reader return is empty when using SQLiteDataReader. When I use the same connection string and sql statement with SQLiteDataAdapter suspected results appears. I supply a part of the static class I use for communication with the database.  The method SenasteBokning using SQLiteDataReader isn’t working. The method SenasteBokning2 using SQLiteDataAdapter works perfect.
What’s wrong with the method SenasteBokning?

I use:
Windows 10
Visual Studio 2017
.net framework 4.5.2 (Was default at creation of Windows Forms application)
Nuget package System.Data.SQLite.Core 1.0.108

```
static class Databas
{
    private static string appPath =     Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
    private static string dbPath = @"\BokningarConvention.db";
    private static string connectionString = "Data Source= " + appPath + dbPath;
    private static SQLiteConnection con;
    private static SQLiteCommand cmd;
    private static SQLiteDataReader reader;
    private static SQLiteDataAdapter adapter;
    private static SQLiteCommandBuilder commandBuilder;
    private static DataTable table; 
    private static string senaste = "SELECT Nummer, NrSammaDag, Datum FROM Bekraftelser WHERE Id = (SELECT MAX (Id) FROM  Bekraftelser)";

    // This don't work
    public static Bokning SenasteBokning()
    {
        Bokning bokning = new Bokning();

        using (SQLiteConnection con2 = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString))
        {
            con2.Open();
            SQLiteCommand cmd2 = new SQLiteCommand(senaste, con2);

            SQLiteDataReader reader2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();

            // Here the reader is empty
            while (reader2.Read())
            {
                // Error at first read
                // should handle results the same way as in SenasteBokning2
                // removed during testing
            }
        }

        return bokning;
    }


    //This works perfekt
    public static Bokning SenasteBokning2()
    {
        Bokning bokning = new Bokning();
        using (SQLiteConnection db = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString))
        {
            adapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(senaste, connectionString);
            commandBuilder = new SQLiteCommandBuilder(adapter);
            table = new DataTable();
            db.Open();
            adapter.Fill(table);

            foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
            {
                int nummer;
                int samma;
                DateTime datum;
                nummer = (int)((long)row["Nummer"]);
                datum = Verktyg.FromDateInteger((int)((long)row["Datum"]));

                if (!row.IsNull("NrSammaDag"))
                {
                    samma = (int)((long)row["NrSammaDag"]);
                    bokning = new Bokning(nummer, samma, datum);
                }
                else
                {
                    bokning = new Bokning(nummer, datum);
                } 
            }
        }
        return bokning;           
    }        
}
```